# CakePHP Flash Messages Display Unwanted Number After

Tags: cakephp

When I call $session->flash() in the view, the flash message does get displayed, however it also displays a number, usually 1, afterward it. See the html produced:

```
<div id="authMessage" class="flash flash_error">Passwords do not match</div>1
```

What is this, why does it now always happen, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you passing a layout as a parameter?  What happens if you debug($_SESSION) - does that show the value you expect or the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're doing this, right?

```
echo $session->flash();
```

You don't need to `echo` the `flash()`, it'll output by itself. What's happening is that `flash()` outputs the message and returns `true`, and you're `echoing` that `true`, which gets turned into '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the echo in front of your flash call $session->flash(); in default.ctp, that should do it